# Amazon Connect check holidays lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, connect

Is it possible to build a lambda function for Amazon connect using AWS that checks the date against holidays and determines whether the flow is in or out of hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a common request.  Just create a Lambda function that compares today's date against an array of holidays or you can hit a database that contains your holidays.  Have Lambda return whether "holiday" is true or false.

This guide will show you how to format the response from Lambda.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html

The picture below demonstrates how to wire up your contact flow to hit the Lambda function and then use "Check contact attributes" to determine if the callback from Lambda returns "holiday" as true or false.

[image]

The picture below here demonstrates how to use the check contact attributes  step to act upon the "holiday" attribute returned from your Lambda function.

[image]

I've modified your python code a bit.  Try something like this to get you started.

```js
from datetime import date

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    d1 = str(date.today())
    d2 = '2018-03-06'
    if d1 == d2:
        return {"holiday":"True"}
    else:
        return {"holiday":"False"}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have done everything that is required but I think it is my code I am failing at. I have never programmed in Python before this so I don't entirely know what I am doing.                                                                                                                 It returns holiday as true but my flow always gets an error in the invoke function block.

Comment: import json, os, urllib.parse

from datetime import date

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    d1 = str(date.today())
    d2 = '2018-03-06'
    if d1 == d2:
        result ={"holiday":"True"};
        return result;
    else:
        holiday ={"holiday":"False"};
        return result;

Comment: You had some minor syntax issues in your code example.  I've updated with a working sample to get you started.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote / mark correct answer if this has been helpful so others can easily find this in the future.